# Why my does drawer navigator screen has no header title, using nested (StackNavigator, DrawerNavigator)

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have problem regarding disappeared header title, Currently I used Nested StackNavigator and DrawerNavigator, I have module when the user is logged in they use the drawer navigator else they will back to stack navigator.

Problem: Why does my header title disappeared ?

Here is my App.js

```
    const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

const UnauthenticatedScreen = () => {   
        
    return (
        <Stack.Navigator>
                <Stack.Screen 
                    name="Login" 
                    component={Login} 
                    options=
                    {{
                        headerShown: false,
                    }}
                />
                <Stack.Screen 
                    name="Registration" 
                    component={Register} 
                    options={{
                        headerStyle: {
                            backgroundColor: '#4ABDFF'
                        },
                        headerTitleStyle: {
                            color: '#fff',
                        },
                        headerTintColor:'#fff',
                    }}
                
                />

                <Stack.Screen 
                    name="Privacy" 
                    component={PrivacyPolicy} 
                    options={{
                        headerStyle: {
                            backgroundColor: '#4ABDFF'
                        },
                        headerTitleStyle: {
                            color: '#fff',
                        },
                        headerTitle:'Privacy Policy',
                        headerTintColor:'#fff',
                    }}
                />

                <Stack.Screen
                    name="RegistrationSuccess"
                    component={RegistrationSuccess}
                    options=
                    {{
                        headerShown: false,
                    }}
                />
        </Stack.Navigator>
    )

}

const AuthenticatedDriverScreen = () => {
    return (
        <Drawer.Navigator drawerContent={props=><CustomDriverDrawer {...props} />} initialRouteName="DriverDashboard">
            <Drawer.Screen
                name="DriverDashboard"
                component={DriverDashboard}
                options={
                    { 
                        drawerLabel: 'Home',
                        drawerIcon: ({focused, color, size}) => (
                            <Icon type="font-awesome" name="home" style={{fontSize:size, color:"black"}} />
                        ),
                        
                    }
                }
            />
            
        </Drawer.Navigator>
    )
}

function Navigator() {
    const isLogin = true;
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
         {isLogin ? <AuthenticatedDriverScreen/> : <UnauthenticatedScreen/>}
        </NavigationContainer>

    )
}
```

**Authenticated User Screen:**

[image: Authenticated Screen]

Very well appreciated for your help.

Comment: drawer not providing header

Comment: @NishargShah question. how have a header title when i acess my dashboard?

Comment: bind both screens into createStackNavigator and you can access it

Comment: can you please deep more explain or have example for that @NishargShah

Comment: please create demo problem in online editor ( snake expo ), so I can easily modify it and solve your problem

Comment: Hi @NishargShah https://snack.expo.io/Xdx8BWWjO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to remember that thing `React Navigation` providing `drawer` functionality and `screen` functionality separately.

for connecting two functionality in one you need to bind the screen with a drawer so you can see both things in one go.

that's why first you need to make one screen navigator that contains single/multiple screen(s) so you can bind that navigator with a drawer like the below code.

```
const BindedScreenComponent = () => {   
    return (
      <Bind.Navigator>
        <Bind.Screen 
            name="Bind" 
            component={() => <Text>Bind</Text>}
        />
      </Bind.Navigator>
    )
}
```

after that, you need to bind that code into the drawer component so the drawer component can render a whole navigator and give you the desire results

```
<Drawer.Screen
    name="DriverDashboard"
    component={BindedScreenComponent} 
    options={
        { 
            drawerLabel: 'Home',
        }
    }
/>
```

snake: https://snack.expo.io/@nishargshah/react-navigation-5-boilerplate

Comment: Hi Nishard Question, How to pass the binding on the CustomDrawer.js ?

Comment: Why you want to pass it in customer drawer?

Comment: Hi @Nisharg. your example is all good, however there is problem on the options. i can't configured the header bar

Comment: headerTintColor:'#fff' if i set this to the options, there is no changing on the binded screens

Comment: can you explain more deep, so incase someone encounter this problem they will understand more what you suggest to me.

Comment: Based on your explanation how the user access the nested navigator screen? example when the user click the Login button if true user will move on the screen AuthenticatedDriverScreen. how the binded  screen component will work on that?

Comment: here is a very good article https://reactnavigation.org/docs/screen-options-resolution/

Answer (score -1):

My Old Explanation is correct for multiple screens bound in one screen but if you want only one screen with one drawer then you can use `headerShown: true` in your drawer options so, it will automatically show the header of the drawer.

Here is the example: https://snack.expo.io/@nishargshah/react-navigation-5-drawer